# merge multiple small json files using pyspark in s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am a newbie in spark.

I have multiple small json files (1kb) in subdirectories of my  s3 bucket. I want to merge all the files present in a single directory. Is there any optimized way in doing this using pyspark.

Directory structure: 
region/year/month/day/hour/multiple_json_files

I have many directories as indicated above and want to merge all files in a single directory.

P.S: I have tried using python but its taking more time, tried s3distcp but its the same result.

Can anyone please help me in this

Comment: use wildcard for `region/year/month/day/hour/` to `*/*/*/*/*/`.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve by below code

First we need to make sure the hadoop aws package is available when we load spark:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell"
```

Next we need to make pyspark available in the jupyter notebook:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

We need the aws credentials in order to be able to access the s3 bucket. We can use the configparser package to read the credentials from the standard aws file.

```
 import configparser
 config = configparser.ConfigParser()
 config.read(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/credentials"))
 access_id = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_access_key_id") 
 access_key = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_secret_access_key")
```

We can start the spark session and pass the aws credentials to the hadoop configuration:

```
 sc=spark.sparkContext
 hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
 hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
 hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", access_id)
 hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", access_key)
```

Finally we can read the data and display it:

```
 df=spark.read.json("s3n://path_of_location/*.json")
 df.show()
```